# {"Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."} format problem

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method `PersianDateToGregorianDate` that I use instead of `Convert.todatetime` for insert my persian date time, and I have an extension method (`ToPersianDate`) for viewing and converting my date time to Persian date in my gridView. But I get this error:

> Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime

when I enter datetime like this 31/2/1398,and in this month we have 31 days :)

That's my `PersianDateToGregorianDate` method (works correctly):

```
public static DateTime PersianDateToGregorianDate(string pDate)
        {
            var dateParts = pDate.Split(new[] { '/' }).Select(d => int.Parse(d)).ToArray();
            var hour = 0;
            var min = 0;
            var seconds = 0;
            return new DateTime(dateParts[2], dateParts[1], dateParts[0],
                                hour, min, seconds, new PersianCalendar());
        }
```

And that's my `ToPersianDate` extension method (I got error in this method):

```
public static DateTime ToPersianDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
            int year = pc.GetYear(dt);
            int month = pc.GetMonth(dt);
            int day = pc.GetDayOfMonth(dt);
            int hour = pc.GetHour(dt);
            int min = pc.GetMinute(dt);

            return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, 0);
        }
```

and I change my DataGridView date Format in my form load :

```
dataGridView1.Columns[5].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Comment: `31/2/1398` is not a valid datetime. How do you set the DateTime variable used to call your ToPersianDate?

Comment: i know that's not valid but when i put this datetime to my `PersianDateToGregorianDate` method ,this 31/2/1398 date convert to a valid date like this : 02/22/2019

Comment: OK, but you are passing a string to PersianDateToGregorianDate and then you split and parse. On the contrary the ToPersianDate returns a DateTime and you cannot have those values in a DateTime. You should give back a string. (Perhaps there is some library that allows you to work with Persian dates directly as DateTime)

Comment: Well checked something on line and it seems that you can just write _return new DateTime(year, month, day, pc);_ then add the hour part and min part but at the end you get the same datetime you have passed as input.

Comment: let me explain: i put this  date (31/2/1398) to `PersianDateToGregorianDate` method, that method convert this (31/2/1398) to this 02/22/2019 date and i insert that in my sql and that's work correctly,when i select my data in `DataGridView` i  see this date(02/22/2019) and i use this `ToPersianDate` method to show my date in `DataGridView` like this 31/2/1398 
but i got that error :(

Comment: Set the FormatProvider for your DataGridView to the Persian CultureInfo. See my updated answer below

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a value of 31 for the month of February in a DateTime variable. You can keep your date into a DateTime variable and don't worry about the internal representation of that date.  When you need to display a Persian date you could just call:

```
public static string ToPersianDate(this DateTime dt)
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fa-Ir");
    return dt.ToString(ci);
}
```

Also if you need to display the date in a DataGridView I think you should set the FormatProvider property to the Persian CultureInfo.

I cannot test it at the moment but you could try

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fa-Ir");
dataGridView1.Columns[5].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = ci;
dataGridView1.Columns[5].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = ci;
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Comment: Note that the default calendar in the `fa-IR` culture is the `GregorianCalendar`, while the optional calendar is the `HijriCalendar`, which has different DateTime rules than the `PersianCalendar`. You'll have to perform a *manual* convertion (as the OP did). What will most probably fail is the `PersianDateToGregorianDate` method. Here, you need `TryParseExact`, specifying the current conversion format.

Comment: @Jimi I experience a default on the PersianCalendar instead. Just creating a _CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fa-Ir"); ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.ToString();_ gives _System.Globalization.PersianCalendar_

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Not even `CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fa");` returns a `PersianCalendar` in any available option. Can you tell me the OS version and the Framework version you're using?

Comment: I am using LinqPad to test the code above. Win 10 Pro latest update 1903 (Italian 64bit) Framework used by LinqPad should be the latest 4.7.2. Let me try with VS 2017

Comment: Confirmed also in VS 2017 with NET 4.7.2 in a console app. 
Just _DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; 
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fa-Ir"); 
Console.WriteLine(ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.ToString());  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString(ci));
            Console.ReadLine();_

Comment: I re-tested it too. Windows 10 returns (2 versions, I also tested 1803) `PersianCalendar`, while Windows 7 (the machine I was working on) returns `GregorianCalendar`. I really didn't remember there was this kind difference. Better write it down.